# SpringData annotation(or the standard way) to use String for MongoDB ObjectId in java for manual references

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am wondering if there exists a way to map String on the java side for manual references to ObjectIds and vice-versa. For example in:

```
User =[{_id: ObjectId('123'),
        pics_id: ObjectId('123'), ...
      }, ... ]
```

pics_id is a manual reference to another collection. The following code:

```
class User{
@Id id;
@Field("pics_id") String picId;
}
```

stores the pics_id as String instead of ObjectId. 
Is there any way to make this happen without the use of the ObjectId class instead of String? IMHO, using ObjectId in the java code would make the code look a bit strange, as some ids are string(such as fields annotated with @Id) and some are objectIds. Thank you.

Comment: @christophstrobl This would be a worthy feature to implement, as I see a lot of interest in the community for a feature like this to handle manual references more gracefully on the java side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the upcoming Spring Data MongoDB 2.2 release it is possible to define the desired target type via the `@Field` annotation.
The type information is passed down to the conversion subsystem so that eg. a plain String can be stored as Code or ObjectId.

```java
class User {

  @Id String id; 
  @Field(targetType = FieldType.OBJECT_ID) 
  String picId;
}
```

Please have a look at the [documentation of 2.2.0.RC1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.2.0.RC1/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters) for more details.

Comment: Fantastic. will check it out. Thanks @Christoph.